# Parse Javascript and Twitter API

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I'm running Parse cloud code in an attempt to display my twitter feed on the webpage. Here is the javascript I have in the html below.

```
<script type="application/javascript">

            Parse.initialize("my app id", "my javascript id");
            enter code herevar Tweets = Parse.Object.extend("Tweets");
var query = new Parse.Query(Tweets);
query.find({
    success: function(results) {
        // results is an array of your Tweets
        console.log(results);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
});

        </script>
```

and here is the output in the console.log

[ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass]

It is showing in my Parse core dashboard as 77 tweets so cloud code is working.

How do I only display the contents in a clean readable format ie. the twitter avatar, message, time, etc.?

I tried following this tutorial below but it was of no help 
https://medium.com/@nannerb/tutorial-storing-tweets-in-parse-via-the-twitter-api-9fe2ee092013

Comment: You need to read the properties of the objects.

Comment: thank you so much SLaks, and how does one go about that?

Answer (score 1):

Probably those objects have a `toString` method that will return the name of the object, you could iterate all properties to check them:

```
success: function(results) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        for (var prop in results[i]) {
            console.log("Property name -> " . prop);
            console.log("Property value -> " . results[i][prop]);
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Thanks taxicala this is what comes up,,   Tweets
index.html:172 0
index.html:172 BU7RjsSaOs
index.html:172 Tweets
index.html:172 1
index.html:172 nraSHHx9PG
index.html:172 Tweets
index.html:172 2
index.html:172 BgoYC88K1n
index.html:172 Tweets
index.html:172 3
index.html:172 aXzmyMpgtv
index.html:172 Tweets
index.html:172 4
index.html:172 8fJ2l7VXZC

Comment: but now how do i make that display the tweets and details themselves